# Why are there naming collisions in Composer's vendor folder? (between bin and hhvm)

Tags: composer-php, hhvm, hacklang

I have been learning to use hacklang and hhvm and I have went about using composer and installing all the needed packages as

```
composer require hhvm/hsl hhvm/hhvm-autoload
composer require --dev hhvm/hhast hhvm/hacktest facebook/fbexpect
```

I have also setup the `.hhconfig` aswell as the `hh_autoload.json` and `hhast-lint.json`

However there is a naming collision between the `Vendor/bin` and `Vendor/HHVM`

Can anyone explain why this is happening or how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because composer copies `vendor/vendor/package/bin/file` to `vendor/bin/file`, causing symbols in `vendor/vendor/package/bin/file` to be defined twice. IT IS EXPECTED.

to avoid naming issues, add the following to your `.hhconfig` :

```
ignored_paths = [ "vendor/.+/tests/.+", "vendor/.+/bin/.+" ]
```